# Disable Chrome’s Data Saver optimization

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

I have problems with image loading on a website in Chrome. Now I figured out that if I manually disable the Data Saver feature of Chrome all works fine.

The [documentation of Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression) describes how to disable this feature – but I can’t get it.

I have tried to add `Cache-Control: no-transform` using a html tag and also by adding `header("Cache-Control: no-transform")` – but both didn’t work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After thinking over my question once more, I realized, that I don’t have to disable the caching in my PHP file than on the images. So I used a htaccess file like the following:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
</FilesMatch>
```

Now the caching for all images is gone and the site works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answer from Karsten. Only instruction I want to add is When you are adding this code in htaccess file.

Keep it on 3 different lines. It gives error if they are in single line.

Also the site will load a bit slower due to non caching.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: So, don't do it till you get that privilege. Wait till you got it.